# Convert method params string[] to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

In some utility libraries I have methods that have a params[] parameter. In many of these cases, these end up as key/value pairs which would be even more useful if I could convert these to a dictionary.

What would be the most efficient method to do this? Can I do this via Linq somehow?

Here is an example:

```
public static Uri appendParams(Uri uri, params string[] parameters)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (parameters == null) {
            return uri;
        }

        var queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(uri.Query ?? "");

        //Would like to convert the params[] argument to a dictionary here
        Dictionary<String, String> paramsDictionary = null; // Not sure best way to do this...

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in paramsDictionary)
        {
            queryStringBuilder.Append(kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value);
        }

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        uriBuilder.Query = queryStringBuilder.ToString();

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: Care to give us an example of what you mean?

Comment: Are the keys and values stored in a specific order inside the array?

Comment: Why don't you just specify a dictionary as the argument type, and let the client create it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov arguments are passed in this order: key, value, key, value etc.

Comment: @RufusL I thought about it, but then I took this approach and not able to come up with the proper method for this, so now I'm curious.

Comment: So you don't allow a key without a value? i.e. no 'switch' params? And if a key is specified more than once, you only use the last specified value?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a string and using it right away (and not using the dictionary for anything else), then you can skip the dictionary creation step and just build your query string from the parameter array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    var concatChar = (i == 0) ? "?" : "&";
    queryString.AppendFormat("{0}{1}={2}", 
        concatChar, parameters[i], parameters[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: Ended up doing it without LINQ: